# Sorting list by the inner elements in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

How that list can be sorted by the inner list elements?

```
my_list = [[False, 3, 82],[True,15,34], [False,22, 33], [True,2, 5], [False,1,67], [False, 22, 44], [True, 6, 99], [True, 14, 34], [False, 2, 82]]
```

I need a list at the final like that;

```
my_list = [[True,2, 5], [True, 2, 99], [True, 14, 34],[True,15,34], [False, 1,67], [False, 2, 82], [False, 3, 44], [False,3, 88], [[False, 22, 44]]
```

It will check the first elements of the inner lists, if there are more than one "True", it will check and sort the second elements. If there are the same numbers, than it will check the third elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
import pprint

my_list = [[False, 3, 82], [True, 15, 34], [False, 22, 33],
           [True, 2, 5], [False, 1, 67], [False, 22, 44],
           [True, 6, 99], [True, 14, 34], [False, 2, 82]]


res = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (not x[0], x[1], x[2]))
pprint.pprint(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[True, 2, 5],
 [True, 6, 99],
 [True, 14, 34],
 [True, 15, 34],
 [False, 1, 67],
 [False, 2, 82],
 [False, 3, 82],
 [False, 22, 33],
 [False, 22, 44]]
```

The idea of:

```
lambda x: (not x[0], x[1], x[2])
```

is to negate the first argument to put the inner list with `True` first, then use the normal int comparison for the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply do it by sorting your list thrice based on key as follow:**

1. First sort your list based on the last element of each sub-list.
2. Then sort on basis of the middle element.
3. Sort based on the first element and in reverse order. That's it.

   ```
   my_list = [[False, 3, 82], [True,15,34], [False,22, 33], [True,2, 5], [False,1,67], [False, 22, 44], [True, 6, 99], [True, 14, 34], [False, 2, 82]]
   my_list.sort(key = lambda x : x[2])
   my_list.sort(key = lambda x : x[1])
   my_list.sort(key = lambda x : x[0], reverse = True)
   print(my_list)
   ```

**Or, you can use a one-liner for the same job:**

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: (not x[0], x[1], x[2]))
```

The advantage of using the `sort` method instead of the `sorted` function is that it is in-place. This means that no extra memory is required.